# Catching in GWT a custom event fired by JS

Tags: javascript, java, events, gwt

I got this code on a JS file :

`this.fire('after-td-click', someData);`

How can I catch this event in GWT ?

Comment: I will recommend to catch the event in js file only and inside handler, call GWT native method. Go through [http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)